# Creating a LabelFrame inside a Tkinter Canvas

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I'm trying to place a `LabelFrame` which displays a `Label` inside a `Canvas` however I receive this error:

> TclError: can't use .28425672.27896648 in a window item of this canvas

Here's my code:

```
from Tkinter import LabelFrame, Label, Tk, Canvas

root = Tk()

canvas = Canvas(root)
canvas.pack()

label_frame = LabelFrame(text="I'm a Label frame")
label = Label(label_frame,text="Hey I'm a Label")

canvas.create_window(10,20,window=label)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make the `label_frame` child of the `canvas`, and pack the `label` inside the frame. Then pass `label_frame` (instead of `label`) to `create_window` .

```
...
label_frame = LabelFrame(canvas, text="I'm a Label frame")
label = Label(label_frame, text="Hey I'm a Label")
label.pack()

canvas.create_window(10, 20, window=label_frame, anchor='w')
...
```

`anchor` is `CENTER` by default. To correctly align, specify anchor as `w`.

Comment: No `Labelframe` is displayed then sorry :(